# Redirects on POST requests that are to untrusted servers is not supported

Tags: support, openid

I implemented the open ID provider from DotNetOpenAuth into my application. It's implemented almost exactly how they did it in their sample open ID provider.

When I try to log into SO using my open ID though, SO doesn't let me and tells me this:

> Redirects on POST requests that are to untrusted servers is not
>   supported.

Not sure how to get this fixed. Basically there is a button that the user can choose "Continue" to authorize the open id request or "Cancel".

I can post the code but it's kind of long. I'm using DotNetOpenAuth 3.4.4.10162, do I need to update?

Comment: I get the same error at the moment when I try to login via my wordpress.com OpenID.