# OpenID Problem - Redirects on POST requests that are to untrusted servers is not supported

Tags: bug, login, openid

Similar to [Wordpress OpenID: Redirects on POST requests that are to untrusted servers is not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245329/wordpress-openid-redirects-on-post-requests-that-are-to-untrusted-servers-is-no) and [Redirects on POST requests that are to untrusted servers is not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118349/redirects-on-post-requests-that-are-to-untrusted-servers-is-not-supported), when I try to log in to rpg.stackexchange.com using my Wordpress OpenID it doesn't work and gives me the error in the subject.

Given the partial guidance in the other questions, I've tried choosing other options and messing with the openid URL manually but no love.

My site is mxyzplk.wordpress.com.  It has a primary domain of geek-related.com.  I've tried putting both in, with http and https, but none of those combinations work.

Comment: See my (entirely unhelpful) answer on the dupe.